# Using CURL with Password Protected Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, cookies, curl

I'm trying to get CURL to work with a Wordpress installation that requires a user to be logged in to see the content. I've exported the cookies from my logged in session and saved them in a cookie jar file. When I run curl, I just get redirected to a login screen. Any idea why?

The command I am running is:

```
curl --cookie cookie_jar.txt -L <url>
```

Comment: curl -u username:password http://your-domain

Comment: Probably because the cookies aren't used to authenticate, only to validate an existing session, and some other parameter ( IP address, user agent string, etc), is used with session id cookie to validate. Just send post request to login form script via curl and then the page needed.

Comment: @hex494D49 that only works if target site supports http basic ( which wp might, but as a generic approach your suggestion won't reliably work)

Comment: @Anthony You might be right :) That's why I left a comment, rather than firing an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make two requests, as the cookie in the cookie jar file that verifies authentication may become stale/expire. The first request should be to the script that handles authentication, which will be the `action` script that the login page's form sends the `POST` request with necessary authentication variables.

```
curl --cookie cookie_jar.txt --data "username=someguy&press=mahpass" -L http://mywordpressblog.com/login.php
```

Now, any subsequent requests using the same cookie jar will send the cookies already in the cookie jar that match the cookie domain:

```
curl --cookie cookie_jar.txt -L http://mywordpressblog.com/page-i-wanted-all-along.php
```